# Polymer function call but no result

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

> Old Question: How can I call a Polymer Function? (check edits, I don't want to cram code in here)

Rewrite:

I have a `<core-scaffold>` that I want to call the `togglePanel()` function. (This sits in `project_root/index.html`.) I do this using:

```
<core-icon-button onclick="document.querySelector('core-scaffold').togglePanel();"
icon="drawer></core-icon-button>
```

In Chrome's Inspector, I can see this causes no errors, but it doesn't do anything on-screen. My code calls this function in `project_root/bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html`:

```
togglePanel: function() {
  this.$.drawerPanel.togglePanel();
}
```

Which in turn calls this function in `project_root/bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html`:

```
togglePanel: function() {
  this.selected = this.selected === 'main' ? 'drawer' : 'main';
}
```

I am either to naive and unexperienced to see the problem, or have a terrible complex bug. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `on-EVENTNAME` is polymer's special declarative event system. You can only use it in the context of a `<polymer-element>` or in an auto-binding template. Calling a custom element's method is the same as calling a native HTML element's method. See http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/customelements.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the problem as well.  The issue is that the closeDrawer(), openDrawer(), and togglePanel() are only usable when size of your screen is less than the value of responsiveWidth.

I think the logic is that if you have the screen real estate you would always want to show the drawer.  Of course this could be tweaked by extending core-drawer-panel and making a custom core-scaffold implementation.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out that a button appears anyway when the width < responsiveWidth.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly fetch the element using query selector and call its method on onclick just like other html pages

```
<button onclick="document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel').togglePanel();">toggle drawer</button>
```

Comment: Using Chrome's inspector, I can see that `document.querySelector('core-scaffold')` works. However, when I try to use `document.querySelector('core-scaffold').togglePanel()` it does nothing and gives no errors. When I use `console.log(....togglePanel)` it shows that the function is defined, but for some reason, nothing happens in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Change the published attribute in core-drawer-panel.html `forceNarrow=true` 
 See @ [Call function on polymer navigation drawer panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29457999/1603689)